# Can I link a script to a google sheets which already has a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets which is linked to a form and a google scripts that was created in the menu of google sheets. This script runs fine and I use it to format the data. However, I have another script which I created from the google developer console, which sends and receives data from a website. I need this second script to get the value of a cell in the google sheets.
How can I link this second form to the google sheets while keeping the script already linked to the sheets?

When looking at responses to other questions they seem to be about individual sheets in a set so just to clarify, when referring to google sheets I mean the whole google sheets document. I only have one sheet anyways.

If it helps: The script I want to add acts a bit like a server and is being deployed by google scripts while the script that is already linked is only run when I call it on the sheets.

Comment: You say `I need this second script to get the value of a cell in the google sheets.` and then you say `How can I link this second form to the google sheets while keeping the script already linked to the sheets?` Are you talking about a script or a form?

Comment: @Cooper Sorry about the confusion, I wasn't sure how to phrase this. I have a google sheets which receives data from a google form. It also has a google script linked to it so that when I run the script, changes appear on the sheets as intended. This works fine. I now want to link a new, separate google app script to the google sheets which was not created through the tools menu in google sheets, meaning that it is not already connected to the google sheets. I am unsure of how to connect the new script to the google sheets. Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which was to link the script to the google sheets using

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID_HERE");
```

I can then use `ss.getActiveSheet().getRange().getValue();`
and other funtions.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is not way of attaching a standalone script to a document making it a bound script (which is the actual terminology for the script linked the the document).

The simplest way would be to copy-paste the code to the other script. You can deploy the bounded script.

If you really need more than one project for whatever reason, you can enable the Apps Script API and use `projects.create` ([read reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create)) to create another one. If you don't know what this means, you probably shouldn't use it as it's finicky at best.